# jquery function to sum vaules from a 10 line array and output to screen

Tags: jquery, arrays

I need to write a jquery function to take vaules from an array, add them together and output the answer to the screen. The array is created with 10 lines, each containing a name followed by 3 numbers, this is currently being output the screen. I need to change the output the the sum of the 3 numbers. So i need the function to go through each line of the array, add the numbers and output to screen.

```
var classdata = [];
var midterm1, midterm2, midterm3, final;

function setup() {
 classdata[0] = "Jane Doe,80,75,90,87";
 classdata[1] = "John Doe,70,65,60,70";
 classdata[2] = "Jack Smith,80,80,90,83";
 classdata[3] = "Jen Smith,90,70,60,75";
 classdata[4] = "Fred Ryan,90,90,86,80";
 classdata[5] = "Chris Martin,40,50,35,40";
 classdata[6] = "Fiona Rowe,50,30,45,45";
 classdata[7] = "Mike Smith,70,90,65,78";
 classdata[8] = "Mary Ryan,85,95,83,75";
 classdata[9] = "Jack Walsh,65,80,73,60";
}

function outputdata() {
 var output="";
 for (i in classdata)
 {
   output+=classdata[i]  + "\n";
 }
$('#resultdata').text(output);
}
```

Comment: Great!   Let us know how it works out.

Comment: What's the question? Maybe it'd be helpful to give us an example of the array.

Comment: this is what i have so far, i'm stuck on the function to read the number from the array, add them then output

Comment: @ais177, Please provide your desire output?

Comment: desired output is the average of the first two numbers out of 50 then the average of the 2nd 2 number out of 50, both added together to giver overall mark

Comment: e.g Jane Doe 84 John Doe 68 Jack Smith 83

Comment: okey then wait for me.

Comment: check it out [link](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/rj5g59x8/)

Comment: Was there something wrong with [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36213251/361762)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want "**Jane Doe 84 John Doe 68 Jack Smith 83**" is not a valid sequence. There are no way to do this. You have to use one rule for every calculation.

My calculation is based on "**desired output is the average of the first two numbers out of 50 then the average of the 2nd 2 number out of 50, both added together to giver overall mark**".

**HTML**

```
<span id="resultdata"></span>
```

**jQuery:**

```
output = "";
var classdata = [];

classdata[0] = "Jane Doe,80,75,90,87";
classdata[1] = "John Doe,70,65,60,70";
classdata[2] = "Jack Smith,80,80,90,83";
classdata[3] = "Jen Smith,90,70,60,75";
classdata[4] = "Fred Ryan,90,90,86,80";
classdata[5] = "Chris Martin,40,50,35,40";
classdata[6] = "Fiona Rowe,50,30,45,45";
classdata[7] = "Mike Smith,70,90,65,78";
classdata[8] = "Mary Ryan,85,95,83,75";
classdata[9] = "Jack Walsh,65,80,73,60";

for (i = 0; i < classdata.length; i++){
    a = classdata[i].split(",");
  sum1 = 0;
  sum2 = 0;
  for(j = 1; j <= 4; j++){
    if(j < 3)
        sum1 = sum1 + parseInt(a[j]);
    else
      sum2 = sum2 + parseInt(a[j]);
  }
  s = Math.ceil(sum1/2) + Math.ceil(sum2/2);
  output += a[0] + " => " + Math.ceil(s/2) + "<br/>";  
}
$('#resultdata').html(output);
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Jane Doe => 84
> John Doe => 67
> Jack Smith => 84
> Jen Smith => 74
> Fred Ryan => 87
> Chris Martin => 42
> Fiona Rowe => 43
> Mike Smith => 76
> Mary Ryan => 85
> Jack Walsh => 70
> ```

Let me know if you have any rule for it or not, try this and give the feedback.

Comment: Thank you this is working for me, I'm moving on to adding records to the array now, hopefully I can work that out :-)

Comment: Why are you rounding up? That throws off the average.

Comment: Because he don't want any floating type value as output, so i ceil the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a combination of [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). jQuery doesn't do anything to help you here, this is all pure JavaScript (except the showing of the output).

```js
var data = ["Jane Doe,80,75,90,87","John Doe,70,65,60,70","Jack Smith,80,80,90,83","Jen Smith,90,70,60,75","Fred Ryan,90,90,86,80","Chris Martin,40,50,35,40","Fiona Rowe,50,30,45,45","Mike Smith,70,90,65,78","Mary Ryan,85,95,83,75","Jack Walsh,65,80,73,60"];

var out = outputdata(data); //get results as an array

$('#resultdata').html(out.join("<br/>")); //use .join() to convert array into combined string

//function to transform an array of strings to string array with name and average score
function outputdata(classdata) {
  //use .map() to transform the array
  var output = classdata.map(function(item) {
    var a = item.split(","); //make an array out of csv
    var name = a.shift(); //take the name out of the array
    
    //sum the remaining items using .reduce()
    var total = a.reduce(function(previous, current) {
      return previous + parseInt(current, 10); //cast to integers
    }, 0);
    
    //return transformed item as a string
    return name + " " + (total / a.length); //divide to average
    
  });
  return output; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resultdata"></div>
```